# Session when navigating through html and ASP.NET pages?

Tags: asp.net, html, cookies

I have this issue: Due to design concerns, the ASP.NET webpage I am currently building will have to be inside an iframe in an HTML page. I must keep a session to store some variables in case the user returns to my ASP page, but I notice that as soon as I go to the HTML, the session dies. I was thinking of using cookies to store the information, but would like to listen to somebody else's opinion first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work to request the same page from an iframe if the user is the same as the iframe request is being made by the user's browser which will still have the session.

Are you sure it's not something simpler like the iframe pointing to a login pgae or something?

Is the iframe using a URL attribute or are you loading the contents of the iframe server side?

Comment: You are right. The Session does persist as long as you are in the same iframe. If even worked when shifting between php (linking to an outside page), html and asp pages. The value was being destroyed elsewhere. My mistake.

Comment: What exactly was your situation? can you explain it more ? I assume that in HTml page's iframe you are navigating between your aspx pages.